# How to edit proc file?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, proc

I want to edit the value of a proc file /proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/gc_interval in the middle of a running kernel. I want to edit the value of this proc file value relative to another value.

According to the lifetime value of function ndisc_router_discovery in file net/ipv6/ndisc.c, I want to toggle the value of gc_intervel between 1 and 30. I searched in google but I can find only creating a new proc entry. But this file is already existing. Kindly tell me how to alter the value of this file on fly.

Edit:
I want to do this by editing the kernel code. I want some extra piece of code added to ndisc.c, that changes the gc_interval value according to the lifetime

Comment: just write (with `echo(1)` or `write(2)`) to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proc entry `sys/net/ipv6/route/gc_interval` is defined in `net/ipv6/route.c`:

```
{
    .procname   =   "gc_interval",
    .data       =   &init_net.ipv6.sysctl.ip6_rt_gc_interval,
    .maxlen     =   sizeof(int),
    .mode       =   0644,
    .proc_handler   =   proc_dointvec_jiffies,
}
```

So the `gc_interval` file is a user-land representation of the integer variable  `init_net.ipv6.sysctl.ip6_rt_gc_interval` with a jiffies-to-seconds conversion (the variable is stored in jiffies while the proc entry handle the value in seconds)

If you need to programmatically alter that value in the kernel, you only need to alter that variable:

```
...
init_net.ipv6.sysctl.ip6_rt_gc_interval = new_gc_interval_sec * HZ;
...
```

*Notes:*

- *the kernel references are based on Linux 3.4.5 sources*
- `<net/net_namespace.h>` *should be included to access* `init_net` *structure*

Answer (score 1):

use sysctl command `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.route.gc_interval=20`

If you want to make this value permenant append `net.ipv6.route.gc_interval=20` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/route/gc_interval
```

/etc/sysctl.conf allow do that's at the start up of the system.

Comment: of course you are right. we can add this line in /etc/rc.local and every thing is done. But my problem is I want to change the value whenever the machine is receiving a router advertisement. So this method will not fit for me. Anyway thank you for your involvement :-)